# Why you don't need to specify the version for some dependencies in Spring Boot project?

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, dependencies

I'm learning about Spring Boot and I see that you don't need to specify the version for some dependencies, but you need to specify the version for other dependencies. Where does the version of this dependencies comes from?

```
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.6.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.dgs</groupId>
    <artifactId>n-tier-and-jackson</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>n-tier-and-jackson</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <paypal.rest.easy.version>2.3.3-RELEASE</paypal.rest.easy.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jersey</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.paypal.springboot</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>${paypal.rest.easy.version}</version>
        </dependency>

...
```

For example in this code you don't need to specify the version for spring-boot-starter-jersey, but you need to specify the version for resteasy-spring-boot-starter. Where does the version for spring-boot-starter-jersey comes from? Thank you!

Comment: for all other spring starter depdencies where we don't mention the versions are picked using the version of the parent spring starter dependecy which is defined at top in the pom.xml of your file

Comment: I strong recommend to use most recent version of Spring Boot which means 2.2.1.RELEASE and not use 1.X anymore cause it's end of life.

Comment: You understand how parent projects work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Dependencies versions are declared in the pom file that you  have specified in the parent section of your pom file

Comment: Thank you for response, I've found the version for spring-boot-starter-jersey dependency in the pom file of the parent section. Then why should I declare the dependency in the dependency section of my pom file? So  if the dependency is there, Why I cannot import a class directly from the pom file of the parent?

Comment: @elvis Its because how the Maven dependency management works. The parent pom declared the dependency in <dependencyManagement> tag. When you declare a dependency in dependencyManagement, you are actually not adding dependency but saying that if any child projects uses the dependency, then use the version declared in the parent pom. So in short, dependencyManagement is to ensure that all your child projects uses the same version consistently.